# How to install mysql properly

Tags: mysql, sql, installation, mysql-8.0

I am trying to install `mysql` in my macbook pro (OS version: 10.15.2).

These are the steps I followed

1. Install mysql community server from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
2. Install mysql workbench from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
3. Open mysql from system preferences and click `initialize database`
   [image]
4. set password for root user under `initialize database`
5. open `.bash_profile` through terminal and set path for mysql

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

6. restart terminal to start mysql server with the following command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

7. enter the password set for root user from `step 4`

After all this I get the following error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sbUsbDWTE8) is the video I followed to install mysql in my system

## [EDIT 1]

staring server with -skip-grant-tables

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

OUTPUT

```
2020-02-25T05:27:00.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/SASHAANKs-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2020-02-25T05:27:00.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2020-02-25T05:27:02.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/SASHAANKs-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default authentication mechanism in MySQL 8 is auth socket. Try setting the root password like this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'my_password';
```

More on this here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

If you can't access the CLI interface at all you should try manually resetting the root password as outlined here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

1. Restart the mysql server with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.
2. Connect to the CLI (no password should be necessary)
3. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
4. Reset root password as described above: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'my_password';`
5. Restart mysql normally

Comment: do I do this in the terminal. I am not able to open mysql shell

Comment: yeah that would be a problem - see link in updated answer

Comment: Hi. I followed this step `B.4.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems` from the link. Even this does not seem to solve the issue. what do I do now??

Comment: Try the step by step instructions from the generic reset I summarized above.  I've used this and it should work.

Comment: And make sure to include the `IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password` in your query.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code for starting server with `--skip-grant-tables`. I guess that returns an error as well. can you take a look?